# kendo grid click new update button no efforts

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kendo UI grid and connect to Mysql,
the function update and read is OK, but when I use create, and input some data in new row, then I click the update but it has no effort.
I don't know what's wrong?
My grid is:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "data/channels.php",
                update: {
                    url: "data/channels.php",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "data/channeladd.php",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "results",
                model: {
                    id: "channelId",
                    fields: {
                        channelName: { validation: { required: true} }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [{ field: "channelName", title: "Channel Name" }, { field: "channelIp", title: "Channel Ip" }, { field: "channelPort", title: "Channel Port" }, { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "172px" }],
        editable: "inline",
        navigable: true,  // enables keyboard navigation in the grid
        toolbar: [ "create" ]  // adds save and cancel buttons
    });
```

And in channeladd.php:

```
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "THE PASSWORD") or die("Unable To Connect To Database Server");
mysql_select_db("THE DB") or die("Unable To Connect To THE DB");

// add the header line to specify that the content type is JSON
header("Content-type: application/json");

    $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    // DISCLAIMER: It is better to use PHP prepared statements to communicate with the database.
    //             this provides better protection against SQL injection.
    //             [http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php][4]

    // get the parameters from the get. escape them to protect against sql injection.

    $channelnName = $request["channelName"];
    $channelnIp = $request["channelIp"];
    $channelnPort = $request["channelPort"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO channel (channelName, channelIp, channelPort) VALUES (".$channelnName.",".$channelnIp.",".$channelnPort.")";

    $rs = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($rs) {
        echo true;
    }
    else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        echo false;
    }
```

[image]

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I click the update but it has no effort..What you mean by this.?Have you checked the console for errors.?

Comment: As the image, I click the Update button in the right side, but it has no effort neither UI update or change the data of the table of database (insert sql command).

Comment: I use google crome to check it,and the console isn't have any error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, I don't know the reason, but while I remove the line:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

It becomes OK any operation. Thanks for attention, Deepu :)